# How to check button is clicked or not in PHP?

Tags: php, laravel, datatable

I have searched for this issue but all solution in javaScript related. I need to check a button is clicked or not. Button (`<a href="something"></a>`) is also link to other page. I have tried but my code is working for when anyone view that page. I want when anyone click on view button. My Code:

```
 $for_linking = preg_replace(array('/\.[A-Z]*/i') , '', $orders->order_file);

 if (isset($_GET['link'])) {
    $link = $_GET['link'];
    if($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == $for_linking){
        $ip_address = gethostbyname(trim(`hostname`));
        $pc_username = getenv("username");

        DB::table('click_counts')->insertGetId([
                 'ip' => $ip_address, 
                  'username' => $pc_username, 
                  'order_id' => $orders->id,
         ]);
    }
 }

 return '<a href="' . url("file").'/'.$orders->order_file.'/?link='.$for_linking.'" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary">View</a>';
```

I have used datatable to show the data. If i don't use `if` condition then data is inserting when i page viewed. But i want when anyone click on `View` then data will be inserted. So i can i use if condition here?

**Below Code is work for just view page:**

```
    $ip_address = gethostbyname(trim(`hostname`));
    $pc_username = getenv("username");

    DB::table('click_counts')->insertGetId([
             'ip' => $ip_address, 
              'username' => $pc_username, 
              'order_id' => $orders->id,
     ]);

    return '<a href="' . url("file").'/'.$orders->order_file.'" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary">View</a>';
```

**Table:**

[image]

Comment: so why you don't use ajax?

Comment: @m.elewa i didn't with ajax much.

Comment: I really don't get what you want to achieve, could you please elaborate this a bit clearer?

Comment: Ajax would be your best option.

Comment: @maio290 i want to insert some data(`ip & pc username`) into database when anyone click on view button(Look at the table picture).

Comment: @Joseph_J can you give an example of ajax?

Comment: Do you want to insert the value every time? Then why don't you make the View button an submit button for a form and send a post request out? That would be pretty pure in PHP and HTML.

Comment: without JS, maybe what you can do is you can create another file like view.php and inside that just add table insertion code and redirect to the order page after inserted. the button link will be view.php

Comment: @maio290 No, i won't value every time. When PC username is different then i will insert these value. My code is work without click on view button(if i don't use if condition). When i just view the table page then its work. Now i want if anyone click any button then insert that button id, ip and pc username.

Comment: Here is a link you can read that should explain some things for you.  Read it and maybe watch some youtube tutorial and search around on SO.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6009206/what-is-ajax-and-how-does-it-work  It's really not that hard.  Once you do it once you'll be ok.

Comment: Here is another link.  In this post there is a complete working script that will help you see the process.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53955326/variable-remains-empty-when-using-ajax-in-sending-query-to-php-file/53955622#53955622

Comment: If you are avoiding Ajax, you could use a session variable. When button is clicked, append to a session variable.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a parameter on the button

```
<a href="something?action=send&id=XX"></a>
```

In php script on page something, you use $_GET for the action.

```
$action = '';
if(isset($_GET['action'])) {
    $action = $_GET['action'];
}
if($action == 'send') {
    // the send buttons was clicked
    $id = $_GET['id'];
}
```

Comment: Henry, i have tried this way, but it doesn't work for me. I want this kind of solution.

Comment: Ok you want a popup on the same page?

Comment: No. The view button will redirect other page.

Comment: I edited the answer, if you ad an unique id tot each link, you will be able to tell wich button was clicked.

Comment: `if($action == 'send') { }` this code is not pass this condition

Comment: When i click on view button then its redirect to`http://localhost /adminorder/public/file/57451.pdf?link=send&id=57451` but why its not passing `if($action == 'send') { }` condition??

Comment: change link in to action or action into link.

Comment: i have changed `action` into `link` but not working.. i think somehow this `if($link == 'send') { }` condition not working. Remember:: In view button click a `pdf` file will be  open/downloaded.

Comment: Ok it is not a php script that opens the pdf? that would be best if you want to register the view.